# jQuery select only one from six selectors, others set to none

Tags: jquery, html

I have six selector, every has got to options. I need to following: if I select from one of all option with `value='eth1a'` then for other selectors set `value='none'`.

I try:

```
\$('.chselect').on('change', function(){
  var prom = \$(this).val();
    if (prom != 'none') {
      \$('.chselect').val('none');
    }
});
```

But it does not work. Will be good one or two class for all selectors.

My HTML:

```
<tr>
  <th class='topL toLeft' rowspan='2'>${SWAP}</th>
  <th class='topL toLeft flowHidden'>Channel&nbsp;Select</th>
    <td colspan='2' class='color-light'>
      <select id='outportsfp1' name='outportsfp1' size='1' class='xchselect' ${OUTPSELS1}>
        <option value='none'>none</option>
        <option value='eth1a'>ETH1a</option>
      </select>
    </td>

    <td colspan='2' class='color-light'>
      <select id='outportsfp1' name='outportsfp2' size='1' class='xchselect' ${OUTPSELS2}>
        <option value='none'>none</option>
        <option value='eth1a'>ETH1a</option>
      </select>
    </td>
    ....

    <td colspan='2' class='color-light'>
      <select id='outportsfp6' name='outportsfp1' size='1' class='xchselect' ${OUTPSELS6}>
        <option value='none'>none</option>
        <option value='eth1a'>ETH1a</option>
      </select>
    </td>                       
</tr>
```

Can I ask for help? Thanks

Comment: what's with the random `\\` s in your code?

Comment: It is escape mark for BASH (programming language).

Comment: also, class name seems to be ".xchselect", not ".chselect"

Comment: this question doesn't have anything to do with bash does it? so why do you have them in your js code?

Comment: @DLeh: yes, you have truth. I should better edit my code. Sorry

Answer (score 3):

You can use [`.not()`](http://api.jquery.com/not/) selector

> Remove elements from the set of matched elements.

*Use*

```
$('.chselect').not(this).val('none');
```